# XML response deserialization problem - WebService

Tags: c#, soap, webservice-client, dynamics-365, xml-deserialization

Good morning,

I'm having trouble getting a response using webservice. It seems that the request is fine because on the server side they receive messages.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient servClient = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

ServiceReference1.TLampInfo tLampInfo = new ServiceReference1.TLampInfo();
ServiceReference1.TRespons directResponse = new ServiceReference1.TRespons();


tLampInfo.Txt = "Test1234";

directResponse = servClient.SendLamp(tLampInfo); <---- error
```

I get a message then I try to download the response:  "Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SendLamp'". What else should I do? How should I use deserialization in this case?

Comment: have you tried something like `var response = servClient.SendLamp(tLampInfo);`?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried, still the same error. I can't even see what the XML in the response looks like.

Comment: Can you show the wsdl? The error would indicate `tLampInfo` is not correct.

Comment: In my opinion, everything is fine here because the request is being sent correctly. The problem is when the response is reading.

Comment: @LaSTeR so why does the error call out the "... body of **request** message..."?

Comment: @Crowcoder 
Sorry, I made a mistake in translating the error from Polish. The error sounds: "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'SendLamp'. Sorry again for the confusion.